# How to use SPARQL query to get field and field count at the same time?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I am new to Semantic Web and SPARQL. I am making a RDFS of concert. It has songs entries like:

```
con:song04
    rdfs:Class con:Repertoire;
    rdfs:label "Deewani Mastani";
    con:performedBy con:artist02.
    con:performedBy con:artist05.
```

I am trying to get list of songs and their count, if they are performed by same artist. I have been trying some tutorials from stackoverflow but does not server my purpose.

The query I am using might be wrong completely, would be really helpful in learning, if someone could help me on this aspects. I am using [Apache Jena Fuseki](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/) to query.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX co: <http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/copyrightonto.owl#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
prefix con: <http://www.example.com/paras/concert#>

#Use SPARQL to count and list the songs that two artists share.
SELECT ?songs (COUNT(?artist) AS ?count)  
WHERE
{ 
  ?s rdfs:label ?songs .
  ?s rdf:type con:Repertoire.
  ?s con:performedBy ?artist.
  ?artist rdf:type con:Artist .
  filter( ?count > 1 )
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but important nonetheless: you are using the resource `rdfs:Class` wrong. It's a class name, not a property. The triple `con:song04 rdfs:Class con:Repertoire` does _not_ say that song 4 is in the class "Repertoire". If that is what you want to express, you should use `rdf:type` instead (which is the property that expresses instance-class relationships).

Comment: @JeenBroekstra: You mean to say, I should be saying `con:song04 ref:type con:Repertoire` instead? Please clarify, thanks

Comment: Yes, minus the typo (it's `rdf`, not `ref`).

Comment: Thank you @JeenBroekstra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```sql
> SELECT ?songs (COUNT(?artist) AS ?count)  
> WHERE
> { 
>   ?s rdfs:label ?songs .
>   ?s rdfs:Class con:Repertoire.
>   ?s con:performedBy ?artist.
>   ?artist rdfs:Class con:Artist .
>   filter( ?count > 1 )
> }
> ```

If you paste that query into the [validator at sparql.org](http://sparql.org/validate/query), you see that it's an error to SELECT a variable that you haven't GROUPed BY when you're using aggregate functions like COUNT.  Your query is *almost* correct though.  You're trying to GROUP BY the song, and COUNT how many artists did that song.  Then you want to take only the results HAVING a count greater than 1.  You do that like this:

```sql
SELECT ?songs (COUNT(?artist) AS ?count)  
WHERE
{ 
  ?s rdfs:label ?songs .
  ?s rdfs:Class con:Repertoire.
  ?s con:performedBy ?artist.
  ?artist rdfs:Class con:Artist .
}
GROUP BY ?songs
HAVING (?count > 1 )
```

Comment: Hi @Joshua, Thanks, Your explanation helped me to understand better. You understood exactly what I was trying to do but I am not getting right answer. :( probably something I am missing, help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ParashNathMishra WIthout knowing exactly what you're expecting as results, it will be difficult to help you fix the query.

Comment: I am trying to list the songs that are performed by more than 2 artist. As mentioned in the question, I would want song04 listed as result as it is perfumed by 2 artists also, display the number of songs that satisfy the condition.

Comment: @parash I don't have your data though. I don't know what my query returns on your data. Without access to your data, I can't debug a query on your data.

Answer (score 1):

According to description given, I totally agree with @Joshua Taylor and believe what you are trying to do can be achieved by the query. Please check if your RDFS is okay.

```
SELECT ?songs (COUNT(?artist) AS ?count)  
WHERE
{ 
  ?s rdfs:label ?songs .
  ?s rdfs:Class con:Repertoire.
  ?s con:performedBy ?artist.
  ?artist rdfs:Class con:Artist .
}
GROUP BY ?songs
HAVING (?count > 1 )
```

Comment: Thank you Suresh, it was really indeed problem with my RDFS.